# MySQL export rows content based on Particular Search String

Tags: mysql

At the outset, below is my table's content:

[image]

What I want to know, is that, is there a way / possibility to export the reportcontent column to a seperate mysql table with table columns -- EXAMINATION , HISTORY ?
That is, the "EXAMINATION:" string content be saved in EXAMINATION column and so "HISTORY:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `create table as select` to do it.

```
create table t2 as 
select 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(reportcontent,'\n',1) as EXAMINATION,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(reportcontent,'\n',-1) as HISTORY
from t1;
```

**SQLFiddle demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dc54/1**